# ASP.MVC 3 routing : how to get url with default action included?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Suppose I have the following routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Now, when you generate an url using Url.Action("Index","MyController") you will get as expected : /MyController

But in one exceptional case, I would like to get the full url /MyController/Index
(without changing the routing)... does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you need the full url (I'm just curious)?

Comment: I have to cases where it can matter...

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in knowing why?

Comment: One case is: I have a silverlight app, that uses url navigation. Index is the page containing the html for the silverlight markup, and added to the url is a fragment containing the page to navigate to : Controller/Index/#MyPage
And clearly Controller/#MyPage won't work...
Also sometimes url's passed to javascript code, where the javascript might add something to the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. But you need to modify the routing.

1. Create an own routing class that derives  `Route`
2. Override the [GetVirtualPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.getvirtualpath.aspx) method to include `/index` for the pages that needs it.
3. Configure the default route using your routing class instead.

Comment: This would be ok, but finally I decided to change the action to Edit in these specific cases and I created an overloaded Url.Action (I'm using T4MVC):

        public static string Action(this UrlHelper url, ActionResult result, string fragment)
        {
            return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl((string) null,(string) null,(string) null,(string) null,(string) null,fragment, result.GetRouteValueDictionary(), url.RouteCollection,
                                         url.RequestContext, true);
        }

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not possible. And it shouldn't matter as both urls will resolve to the same controller action.